# ffmpeg adding image overlay to video output

Tags: ffmpeg

HI i am trying to add image to video and generate output.
Here is my command
ImagesFFMPeg Command is:

```
-y -i /storage/sdcard/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4 -i /sdcard/android.png -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]overlay=10:10[out] -map [out] -map 0:a -vcodec h264 -pix_fmt yuv420p /storage/sdcard/overlay.mp4
```

**EDITED** Video that is getting generated in **0 Bytes corrupted** is there anything i am doing wrong here.

```
    ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
12-29 01:37:59.926 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
12-29 01:37:59.926 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/i686-linux-android- --arch=x86 --cpu=i686 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/x86 --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -march=i686' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
12-29 01:37:59.926 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
12-29 01:37:59.926 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
12-29 01:37:59.926 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
12-29 01:37:59.926 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
12-29 01:37:59.926 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
12-29 01:37:59.926 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
12-29 01:37:59.926 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
12-29 01:37:59.926 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
12-29 01:37:59.926 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/sdcard/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4':
12-29 01:37:59.926 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:   Metadata:
12-29 01:37:59.926 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     major_brand     : isom
12-29 01:37:59.926 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     minor_version   : 512
12-29 01:37:59.926 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     compatible_brands: mp41
12-29 01:37:59.926 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
12-29 01:37:59.926 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     title           : Big Buck Bunny
12-29 01:37:59.926 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     artist          : Blender Foundation
12-29 01:37:59.926 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     composer        : Blender Foundation
12-29 01:37:59.936 26806-26937/practice.com.ffmpegprac D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 478K, 14% free 4653K/5372K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
12-29 01:37:59.936 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     date            : 2008
12-29 01:37:59.936 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     encoder         : Lavf52.14.0
12-29 01:37:59.936 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:   Duration: 00:09:56.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 867 kb/s
12-29 01:37:59.936 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x180 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 702 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
12-29 01:37:59.936 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     Metadata:
12-29 01:37:59.946 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:       creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
12-29 01:37:59.946 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:       handler_name    : VideoHandler
12-29 01:37:59.946 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 159 kb/s (default)
12-29 01:37:59.946 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     Metadata:
12-29 01:37:59.946 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:       creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
12-29 01:37:59.946 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:       handler_name    : SoundHandler
12-29 01:37:59.946 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: Input #1, png_pipe, from '/sdcard/android.png':
12-29 01:37:59.946 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:   Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
12-29 01:37:59.946 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     Stream #1:0: Video: png, pal8(pc), 429x343, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
12-29 01:37:59.976 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] using SAR=1/1
12-29 01:37:59.976 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] using cpu capabilities: none!
12-29 01:37:59.976 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] profile High, level 1.2
12-29 01:37:59.976 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] 264 - core 148 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
12-29 01:37:59.976 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/sdcard/overlay.mp4':
12-29 01:37:59.976 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:   Metadata:
12-29 01:37:59.976 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     major_brand     : isom
12-29 01:37:59.976 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     minor_version   : 512
12-29 01:37:59.986 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     compatible_brands: mp41
12-29 01:37:59.986 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     date            : 2008
12-29 01:37:59.986 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     title           : Big Buck Bunny
12-29 01:37:59.986 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     artist          : Blender Foundation
12-29 01:37:59.986 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     composer        : Blender Foundation
12-29 01:37:59.986 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
12-29 01:37:59.986 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 320x180 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
12-29 01:37:59.986 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     Metadata:
12-29 01:37:59.986 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:       encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libx264
12-29 01:37:59.986 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     Side data:
12-29 01:37:59.986 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:       unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
12-29 01:37:59.996 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
12-29 01:37:59.996 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:     Metadata:
12-29 01:37:59.996 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:       creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
12-29 01:37:59.996 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:       handler_name    : SoundHandler
12-29 01:37:59.996 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:       encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 aac
12-29 01:37:59.996 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: Stream mapping:
12-29 01:37:59.996 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:   Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
12-29 01:37:59.996 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:   Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
12-29 01:37:59.996 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:   overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
12-29 01:37:59.996 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress:   Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
12-29 01:37:59.996 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
12-29 01:38:00.436 26806-26937/practice.com.ffmpegprac D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 491K, 14% free 4648K/5384K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
12-29 01:38:00.436 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: frame=   67 fps=0.0 q=28.0 size=      11kB time=00:00:02.88 bitrate=  32.1kbits/s speed=5.76x    
MainActivity: command in progress: frame= 3081 fps=220 q=28.0 size=    2230kB time=00:02:08.51 bitrate= 142.1kbits/s speed=9.16x    
n progress: frame= 8419 fps=227 q=28.0 size=    6176kB time=00:05:50.89 bitrate= 144.2kbits/s speed=9.46x    
12-29 01:38:37.506 26806-26937/practice.com.ffmpegprac D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 479K, 15% free 4610K/5384K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
147.1kbits/s speed=9.25x    
12-29 01:39:02.076 26806-26937/practice.com.ffmpegprac D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 453K, 14% free 4652K/5384K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
12-29 01:39:02.086 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: frame=13802 fps=222 q=28.0 size=   10320kB time=00:09:35.16 bitrate= 147.0kbits/s speed=9.26x    
12-29 01:39:02.586 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: frame=13917 fps=222 q=28.0 size=   10404kB time=00:09:39.96 bitrate= 147.0kbits/s speed=9.26x    
12-29 01:39:03.086 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: frame=14033 fps=222 q=28.0 size=   10486kB time=00:09:44.81 bitrate= 146.9kbits/s speed=9.26x    
12-29 01:39:03.586 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: frame=14154 fps=222 q=28.0 size=   10571kB time=00:09:49.84 bitrate= 146.8kbits/s speed=9.27x    
12-29 01:39:04.076 26806-26937/practice.com.ffmpegprac D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 464K, 15% free 4620K/5384K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
12-29 01:39:04.086 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: frame=14265 fps=222 q=28.0 size=   10648kB time=00:09:54.49 bitrate= 146.7kbits/s speed=9.27x    
12-29 01:39:04.416 26806-26937/practice.com.ffmpegprac D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 471K, 15% free 4622K/5384K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
12-29 01:39:04.416 26806-26937/practice.com.ffmpegprac D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 478K, 15% free 4623K/5384K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
12-29 01:39:04.426 26806-26937/practice.com.ffmpegprac D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 364K, 14% free 4660K/5384K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
12-29 01:39:04.426 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: frame=14315 fps=222 q=-1.0 Lsize=   11125kB time=00:09:56.37 bitrate= 152.8kbits/s speed=9.25x    
12-29 01:39:04.426 26806-26937/practice.com.ffmpegprac D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 406K, 14% free 4679K/5384K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
12-29 01:39:04.426 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: video:1266kB audio:9453kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 3.784636%
12-29 01:39:04.436 26806-26937/practice.com.ffmpegprac D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 465K, 15% free 4627K/5424K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
12-29 01:39:04.436 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] frame I:58    Avg QP:11.91  size:  2535
12-29 01:39:04.436 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] frame P:3607  Avg QP:25.51  size:   187
12-29 01:39:04.436 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] frame B:10650 Avg QP:32.15  size:    44
12-29 01:39:04.436 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] consecutive B-frames:  0.8%  0.0%  0.0% 99.2%
12-29 01:39:04.436 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] mb I  I16..4: 68.4% 11.5% 20.1%
12-29 01:39:04.456 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] mb P  I16..4:  0.7%  0.6%  0.6%  P16..4:  4.4%  1.5%  0.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:91.5%
12-29 01:39:04.456 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.2%  0.0%  B16..8:  2.8%  0.6%  0.1%  direct: 0.1%  skip:96.1%  L0:50.1% L1:42.6% BI: 7.2%
12-29 01:39:04.456 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] 8x8 transform intra:29.0% inter:44.2%
12-29 01:39:04.456 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 24.3% 29.8% 22.0% inter: 0.7% 0.6% 0.2%
12-29 01:39:04.456 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 70% 30%  0%  0%
12-29 01:39:04.456 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 13%  7% 80%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
12-29 01:39:04.466 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 32% 25%  2%  2%  2%  2%  2%  3%
12-29 01:39:04.466 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 50% 24% 25%  1%
12-29 01:39:04.466 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.1% UV:0.0%
12-29 01:39:04.466 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] ref P L0: 73.9%  7.2% 13.6%  5.2%  0.0%
12-29 01:39:04.466 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] ref B L0: 71.4% 24.4%  4.3%
12-29 01:39:04.466 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] ref B L1: 94.2%  5.8%
12-29 01:39:04.476 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] kb/s:17.37
12-29 01:39:04.476 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command in progress: [aac @ 0xb8e8f280] Qavg: 446.027
12-29 01:39:04.476 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 571K, 16% free 4599K/5424K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
12-29 01:39:04.476 26806-26806/practice.com.ffmpegprac I/MainActivity: command success: WARNING: linker: /data/data/practice.com.ffmpegprac/files/ffmpeg has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
                                                                       ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
                                                                         built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
                                                                         configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/i686-linux-android- --arch=x86 --cpu=i686 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/x86 --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -march=i686' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
                                                                         libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
                                                                         libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
                                                                         libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
                                                                         libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
                                                                         libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
                                                                         libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
                                                                         libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
                                                                         libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
                                                                       Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/sdcard/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4':
                                                                         Metadata:
                                                                           major_brand     : isom
                                                                           minor_version   : 512
                                                                           compatible_brands: mp41
                                                                           creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
                                                                           title           : Big Buck Bunny
                                                                           artist          : Blender Foundation
                                                                           composer        : Blender Foundation
                                                                           date            : 2008
                                                                           encoder         : Lavf52.14.0
                                                                         Duration: 00:09:56.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 867 kb/s
                                                                           Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x180 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 702 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
                                                                           Metadata:
                                                                             creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
                                                                             handler_name    : VideoHandler
                                                                           Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 159 kb/s (default)
                                                                           Metadata:
                                                                             creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
                                                                             handler_name    : SoundHandler
                                                                       Input #1, png_pipe, from '/sdcard/android.png':
                                                                         Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
                                                                           Stream #1:0: Video: png, pal8(pc), 429x343, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
                                                                       [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] using SAR=1/1
                                                                       [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] using cpu capabilities: none!
                                                                       [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] profile High, level 1.2
                                                                       [libx264 @ 0xb8e776c0] 264 - core 148 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
                                                                       Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/sdcard/overlay.mp4':
                                                                         Metadata:
                                                                           major_brand     : isom
                                                                           minor_version   : 512
                                                                           compatible_brands: mp41
                                                                           date            : 2008
                                                                           title           : Big Buck Bunny
                                                                           artist          : Blender Foundation
                                                                           composer        : Blender Foundation
                                                                           encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
                                                                           Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 320x180 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
                                                                           Metadata:
                                                                             encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libx264
                                                                           Side
```

Comment: Looks like an Android issue, permissions maybe?. ffmpeg is reporting an output size of `11125kB`

Comment: @Mulvya I am running it on KitKat

Comment: @Mulvya original video is around 30-35 MB but output video size varies and it says cannot play media.

Comment: Your png does not have transparency and it's larger than the base video. As for playback, try adding `-profile:v main -movflags +faststart`

Comment: Is it mandatory to have transparency? I have a use case where i may or may not have transparency for some images.

Comment: I even tried movie overlay it also is not working -y -i /storage/sdcard/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4 -vf movie=/storage/sdcard/android.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-3:main_h-overlay_h-3 [out] /storage/sdcard/overlay.mp4